# SQL Server : scalar function XML Result google maps api

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do reverse geocoding via google API and get Full address from result of that API, I'm going to use sql server 2012 because I have database on that and I need to generate some report from existing LAt/Lon in database then I need a function in SQL to get my result .

I have a SQL query which is I get result without any error

```
DECLARE @Lat nvarchar(50),@Lon nvarchar(50)
SET @Lat = '22.298828'
SET @Lon = '114.172596'


DECLARE  @xml TABLE ( yourXML XML )
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(MAX) 

DECLARE @QS varchar(50)
SELECT @QS = '&date='+convert(varchar(25),getdate(),126)
SELECT @URL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=' + @Lat + ',' + @Lon + '&sensor=false'  + @QS

DECLARE @Response VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MXML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

BEGIN TRY
EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', @Response OUT 
INSERT @xml ( yourXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

SELECT  @MXML.value('(//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')

SELECT  yourXML.value('(//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') from @xml
```

if you run that query you get NULL result and full result because I use 2 different method.

**Null Result :**

First I just tried to use `@Response VARCHAR(8000)` then I just to understand the code, the result that I obtain from the URL is larger than 8000 characters, then, I changed that to `VARCHAR(MAX)` but same error, to get all data, and XML structure finish incomplete, giving as result a NULL when I try to make a SELECT.

I know that I can't use INSERT with EXEC inside a scalar Function because of side-effecting operator. But when I use insert in table I getting my result.

I need a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_ADDRESS_FROM_LatLon] 
(
    @Lat nvarchar(50),@Lon nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS  NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN ...
```

which is send LAT / LON and return Full address

please do not ask me to Create and Run a CLR or SSIS package ... , for that report I can't use those methods ,I need to have a function for that report.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried making your data type into text? which has a maximum length of 2,147,483,647 characters.